# How to use view offset and zoom properties on camera in three.js in parallel

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, trigonometry, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to program a three.js scene with a `PerspectiveCamera`. The canvas will show a sub-region of the whole camera view and it will also have a zoom factor. I've double checked that my offset numbers are good and the zoom factor makes sense.

At full vertical fit they are

```
current zoom 1 
x 714.4099378881989 y 0 w 3755.1801242236024 h 3888
```

The offset works perfectly when the zoom is 1 but when the zoom factor is changed, everything goes off the rails. The zoom > 1 also works as expected with no view offset and targeting the center of the frustum. I'm using `TrackballControls` but they shouldn't be at play here since I'm setting all values programatically.

The relevant camera update function that three in the `PerspectiveCamera` class is

```
    updateProjectionMatrix: function () {

        var near = this.near,
            top = near * Math.tan( _Math.DEG2RAD * 0.5 * this.fov ) / this.zoom,
            height = 2 * top,
            width = this.aspect * height,
            left = - 0.5 * width,
            view = this.view;

        if ( this.view !== null && this.view.enabled ) {

            var fullWidth = view.fullWidth,
                fullHeight = view.fullHeight;

            left += view.offsetX * width / fullWidth;
            top -= view.offsetY * height / fullHeight;
            width *= view.width / fullWidth;
            height *= view.height / fullHeight;

        }

        var skew = this.filmOffset;
        if ( skew !== 0 ) left += near * skew / this.getFilmWidth();

        this.projectionMatrix.makePerspective( left, left + width, top, top - height, near, this.far );

        this.projectionMatrixInverse.getInverse( this.projectionMatrix );

    },
```

My initial reaction is that the fov is for the full view but should be adjusted for sub-views or that I should be dividing the zoom by some factor derived from the sub-view size but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

In my update function I was doing

```
    this.zoom = zoom;

    this.setViewOffset(
      full.w,
      full.h,
      offset.x,
      offset.y,
      offset.w,
      offset.h
    );

    this.controls.update();
```

but what I needed to do was change the zoom so that it was relative to the offset

`this.zoom = zoom * (offset.h / full.h)`